# Thingsboard unable to reach local host

Tags: localhost, thingsboard

After successfully installing thingsboard with the instruction provided by this webpage: https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/windows/?windowsThingsboardQueue=kafka

I wasn't able to commence the thingsboard service as I can't reach the local host after starting thingsboard via cmd as per instructed.

I've inserted my log file and thingsboard.yml in the following link:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1VuxT8hKnqWMPo1zBh4iQFglHySfcwVNG?usp=sharing

Beside that, I've tried to run resmon.exe on my pc to see the listening port and make the necessary changes to the local host and mqtt address but after launching thingsboard, the amended address wasn't reflected.

Hope someone could enlighten me on how to resolve this, thanks in advance

Comment: So after I head into C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
I bind the address of local host to 127.0.0.1
but it still can't connect to the localhost 8081

Comment: you log sais `2020-08-29 11:11:18,270 [main] INFO  o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)`. So it should be port 8080 instead of 8081

Comment: Oh okay thanks for the headsup
I've also resolved the problem because I'm using In-memory instead of kafka so I had to change the queue configuration in order for the localhost to be reached

In fact the installation guide is very complete

Answer (score 0):

The Queue Configuration was set by default to be 'kafka' so I had to change it to 'In-memory' as it was what I originally set in order for the local host to be reached.

Thank you for all your assistance. A kind note: to check back the configuration for the setting if you guys encounter such problem again.